# Appmaker Navigate to a dynamic page

Tags: google-app-maker

i've got a straightforward problem. I'm using a grid to create a large navigation page, based off a lookup table, but this doesn't work for the onclick. Why not?

```
var p = widget.datasource.item.InputFormPageName;
console.log(p); //LOOKS GOOD
var pagestring = "app.pages."+p;
console.log(pagestring); //LOOKS GOOD
app.showPage(pagestring);
```

Expected behavior: app opens pages "pagestring" 
Actual behavior,> throws error:

> (TypeError) : Cannot read property '_d' of undefined at 
>   EveryFlavor.PagePanel.Grid1.Grid1Cell.onClick:5:5

The simpler

```
app.showPage(app.pages.p);
```

Threw the same error as does

```
   app.showPage(app.pages[p]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are trying to compose the path to the object using dot notation. This won't work. Instead, please use the square brackets notation:

```
var p = widget.datasource.item.InputFormPageName;
app.showPage(app.pages[p]);
```

Comment: That did work that time, I must have had something else killing the script above it when I tested before, thanks M.